# IBM Worklight: Request to call Worklight server every < 1s

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Currently I have encountered an issue about the client app attempting to call Worklight server services every < 1s. Here is the log produced from LogCat.

From my experience, if the server cannot be connected, there will not be so many request attempting to connect to Worklight server.

May I know if there is any setting problem instead?

```
08-29 23:20:51.949: D/MobileTreeApp(11294): Request [https://xxx:443/xxx/apps/services/api/xxx/android/query]
08-29 23:20:52.114: D/MobileTreeApp(11294): Request [https://xxx:443/xxx/apps/services/api/xxx/android/query]
08-29 23:20:52.289: D/MobileTreeApp(11294): Request [https://xxx:443/xxx/apps/services/api/xxx/android/query]
08-29 23:20:52.459: D/MobileTreeApp(11294): Request [https://xxx:443/xxx/apps/services/api/xxx/android/query]
08-29 23:20:52.639: D/MobileTreeApp(11294): Request [https://xxx:443/xxx/apps/services/api/xxx/android/query]
08-29 23:20:52.809: D/MobileTreeApp(11294): Request [https://xxx:443/xxx/apps/services/api/xxx/android/query]
08-29 23:20:52.979: D/MobileTreeApp(11294): Request [https://xxx:443/xxx/apps/services/api/xxx/android/query]
```

**EDIT2:**

This only happens in Worklight cluster.

Environment: Worklight 5.0.6, WAS ND 8.5

Comment: Not sure if this is the heartbeat from client to server, but maybe this helps: [WL.Client.setHeartBeatInterval](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_setheartbeatinterval.html)

Comment: I will give a try but I think if it is the heartbeat from client to server, the URL will be something like "https://xxx:443/xxxxx/heartbeat". Moreover, the default setting of heartbeat should be 7 mins if I remember correctly. There will not be so frequent request ...

Comment: Oh, you're right, it doesn't look like it's a heartbeat. Ignore my comment.

Comment: Hi cnandreu, I found that this only happens in cluster. Do you have any idea why is it so?

Comment: All requests fail? WL server is not stateless. In a clustered environment you must guarantee that a client will always communicate with the same server that initialized the session. There's a page in [the docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_setting_up_WL_liberty_8_5_cluster_env.html) that goes into more details, specifically it says *ensure that session affinity is enabled*. Maybe you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and logs to provide more info regarding the session?

Comment: Thanks for the info cnandreu. I will go through the info into details. If so, that means if one of the server failed after session is initialized, there will be problem when it is connected to another server?

Comment: FYI I'm not a server-side person, but AFAIK if the server that established the session stops working, WL will try to re-init when you, for example, call an adapter procedure. Every challenge is a new req/res, assuming you guarantee [session affinity](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/btt/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.btt.channels.doc_7.0%2Fdoc%2Fconcepts%2Fkeyfea%2Fse_id_aff.html) and the client passes all the challenges, you should have a working session with a new WL server in your cluster.

Comment: @red23jordan, as the app is released, is this resolved?

Comment: I believe this question is same as the following. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626621/worklight-6-2-android-send-multiple-requests-to-the-worklight-server

Comment: @IdanAdar, yes this is working now by some setting in IIS to let session affinity enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When session affinity is enabled, this problem is resolved.